# Auto increment Number not working in Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have tried to insert data with simple insert statement but it is not increasing auto increment field ID.

My Query is

```
Insert into [Product]([Name],[Category]) values('abc','xyz')
```

and my table structure is:

```
Mstr_Product Id number AutoNumber Name Text Category  Text
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution

Insert into Product select 'abc','xyz'

It will automatically increase auto ID